# How to open bigbluebutton development environment running locally on linux in android phone browser

Tags: localhost, local, bigbluebutton

I have installed bigbluebutton development environment on my Linux and it is running locally, now i want to open the local app on my phone (android) so that i can detect the type of phone etc. Does anyone know how i can run my development app running locally in Linux on my phone; Your help is appretiated.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by " development app" and "development environment". When you run BBB with a self signed certificate you set a host name,  then you would call BBB like "https://<hostname>/<path>" where <path> points to a nginx location block in the  BBB's server nginx.conf. Typically you would have a location set up in BBB's server nginx say "myapp" so your URL would look like    "https://<hostname>/myapp". See here for how you would access this URL from your phone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to open bigbluebutton web app running locally on linux in mobile phone,

1. Turn on your PC hotspot.
2. Connect to your PC hotspot on mobile.
3. Now type the localhost URL in your mobile browser, i.e. if my app is running on url https://localhost:8080/ then i will type same URL in mobile browser.
4. Now you can use the web app similar to how you would use it on your PC.